# problema al vaciar modelo de JList

Tags: java, java-swing

**Tengo este problema** o fallo de lógica que no estoy pudiendo resolver.

Tengo una base de datos conectada a mi aplicación de Java y una `JList` muestra según la selección de un `JComboBox` los diferentes datos de las personas.

Los datos son mostrados y funciona perfecto, pero me gustaría limpiar el modelo de la `JList` cada vez que selecciono una opción del `JComboBox` para ver los datos y que la lista no se haga enorme.

**Lo que intenté:**

Intente limpiar el modelo de la lista siempre antes de cargarla, funciona la primera vez solo si selecciono una opción diferente pero cuando vuelvo a seleccionar la misma opción la lista quedaría vacía.

Intente usar un método que limpiara la lista a través del observador, limpiando la lista antes de cargar la lista y tuve los mismos resultados.

**Este es el código:**

```
package Interfaz;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import logica.Persona;
import sentencias.Sentencia;

public class PanelLista extends JPanel implements Observador {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1590620308571557484L;
  JScrollPane scrollPane;
  DefaultListModel<Persona> modelo = new DefaultListModel<Persona>();
  JList <Persona> lista; 

  @Override
  public void recibirSentencia(Sentencia sentencia) {
  try {
    while(sentencia.getRs().next()) {//siempre que exista una fila por mostrar devuelve true
      int id = sentencia.getRs().getInt(1); //la primera columna de dicha tabla.
      String nombre = sentencia.getRs().getString(2);
      String apellido = sentencia.getRs().getString(3);
      String direccion = sentencia.getRs().getString(4);
      String email =sentencia.getRs().getString(5);
      String ciudad = sentencia.getRs().getString(6);

      System.out.println(id + nombre + apellido + direccion + email + ciudad);
      modelo.addElement(new Persona(id,nombre,apellido,direccion,email,ciudad));
    }
  } catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

@Override
public void limpiarLista() {
  modelo.clear();
}   

public PanelLista() {
  lista= new JList<Persona>(modelo);
  scrollPane = new JScrollPane(lista);
  this.add(scrollPane);
}
```

---

```
package Interfaz;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import sentencias.Sentencia;

public class PanelOrden extends JPanel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5464990209867624348L;
  //modelo de lista, lista, etc
  DefaultComboBoxModel<Sentencia> modeloComboBox = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Sentencia>();
  JComboBox<Sentencia> seleccion = new JComboBox<Sentencia>(modeloComboBox);
  private Observador observador;

  public PanelOrden() {
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    modeloComboBox.addElement(new Sentencia("select * from personas","Todos"));
    modeloComboBox.addElement(new Sentencia("select id,nombre,apellido,direccion,email,ciudades.nombre_ciudad from artistas.personas join artistas.ciudades on (personas.ciudades = ciudades.id_ciudad)","todo con ciudad"));
    seleccion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        observador.limpiarLista();
        Sentencia temp = (Sentencia) seleccion.getSelectedItem();
        observador.recibirSentencia(temp);
      } 
    });
    this.add(seleccion);
  }

  public void notificar(Observador observador) {
    this.observador = observador;
  }
}
```

---

```
package Interfaz;

import sentencias.Sentencia;

public interface Observador {
  public void recibirSentencia(Sentencia sentencia);
  public void limpiarLista();
}
```

Comment: Quizás no necesites limpiar la lista solo con poner luego del while de recibirSentencia asignar el modelo actualizado a la lista: lista.setModel(modelo). Perdorn si necesitas limpiar el modelo. El setMoeel refrescará la lista con el nuego modelo

Comment: me estaría ocurriendo lo mismo

Comment: Porque? Si la lista la actualizas apenas carga el modelo.

Comment: Descubrí cual era el problema, era un fallo de lógica cuando guardaba los datos, nunca cerraba la query

Comment: Ok, que bueno!. Deberias poner el detalle de la solución por si acaso alguien se tope con un problema simila. :)